# Handler/Runnable delays producing events that are out of sync sometimes

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, delay, runnable

When trying to learn how to create a delay I researched and found the dominant answer to be to use Handler/Runnable/postDelayed.

```
                        Handler handler=new Handler();
                        final Runnable r = new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                delayedMethod();
                            }
                        };
                        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

That worked ok for a while, but I've added a few more things going on and now they are sometimes happening in the wrong order.

This set of events:

paintScreen1()
...
delayedPaintScreen2()
...
paintScreen3()

is screwing up (sometimes) and doing this:

paintScreen1()
...
paintScreen3()
...
delayedPaintScreen2() (runs last and gets messed up by the actions of paintScreen3)

There doesn't seem to be another good way to create delays - one that doesn't create threads.

Solutions I have tried in order to make sure the code events run in the proper order:

0 Putting the main process inside one big synchronized block.

1 Putting the synchronized keyword in the method name of every method involved in the main process.

2 Putting the synchronized keyword only on the method in the Runnable.

3 Taking away the Handler/Runnable/postdelayed and replacing with handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0,1000)

4 Making one Handler instance variable, used by every Handler/Runnable block (as opposed to Handler handler1, handler2, handler3, etc.)

5

```
                        Handler handler=new Handler();
                        final Runnable r = new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                waitOver = true;
                            }
                        };
                        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

                        while (waitOver == false) {

                        }
                        delayedMethod();
                        waitOver = false;
```

My next attempt may be to try to used the Thread class somehow so I can call thread.join().
When that fails the next thing will be very long and complicated, I fear.

Any suggestions?

Any simple examples of a solution?

Thanks

Edit: I may be confused about whether Handler/Runnable results in literal threading or not.

Edit: It's a game. User makes a move, screen updated to show the move, calculation tells that they scored a point, recolor the boxes on the screen, add delay to allow user to see their point, then call method to removed colored squares, when that method completes and we return to the method that called it (containing the Handler/runnable), the code continues down to a point where it calls another method that results in a random square of the board being turned purple. So it should happen user-move, repaint to show point scored, delay so user can see point scored, repaint to erases squares, then random purple square happens. Sometimes what will happen (as far as I can tell) is the random purple square will execute before it should, choose one of the squares where the point was scored, interfere, and make it so the cleanup method gets confused and fails to cleanup.

mainmethod() {
...
if (pointscored) {
   squaresglow();
...
//delay so user can see the glow before the cleanup happens
Handler-runnable
cleanup();
postdelayed
}
...
purpleSquare();
}

I hope this is not even more confusing. purpleSquare runs before cleanup and things get screwed up.

Edit:
Tried this:
6

```
                        CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
                        Handler handler=new Handler();
                        final LatchedRunnable lr = new LatchedRunnable(doneSignal);
                        handler.postDelayed(lr, COMPUTER_MOVE_DELAY);
                        try {
                            doneSignal.await();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        class LatchedRunnable implements Runnable {
                            private final CountDownLatch doneSignal;

                            LatchedRunnable(CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
                                this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
                            }

                            public void run() {
                                 delayedProcess();
                                 doneSignal.countDown();                                                                                                                                                               
                            }
                        }
```

7

```
                        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
                        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    Looper.prepare();
                                    Handler handler=new Handler();
                                    final Runnable r = new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        public void run() 
                                        {
                                            delayedMethodCleanupCalc();
                                        }
                                    };
                                    handler.postDelayed(r, 4000);
                                } finally {
                                    latch.countDown();
                                }  
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            latch.await();
                            delayedMethodPaintScreen();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // todo >> handle exception
                        }
```

Comment: can you post some more of your code, and a elaborate a bit more about how it messes up? Its hard to tell what is going wrong from what you've posted.

Comment: I think it might be more confusing to see it, but I will try to explain it better. See Edit.

Answer (score 1):

> purpleSquare runs before cleanup and things get screwed up
>
> ```
> mainmethod() {
> ...
> if (pointscored) {
>     squaresglow();
>     ...
>     //delay so user can see the glow before the cleanup happens
>     Handler-runnable
>         cleanup();
>     postdelayed
> }
> ...
> purpleSquare();
> }
> ```

You have a design flaw here. Think of Handlers as a queue of messages that will execute code "later" whenever the processor decides to process messages and postDelayed as an inexact way to stuff that message at the bottom of the queue.  If you call postDelayed and you still have lines of code left in the current method to execute, chances are very good that those lines will execute before postDelayed messages are even received.

What you are trying to do is to make sure purpleSquare() gets called after the pointscored routine has done it's job, which may require waiting for it to finish.  PostDelaying to the message queue is not what you should be doing in this case.  What you should be using is a semaphore and a pointScored thread.

Consider the following code design:

```
final Runnable pointScoredTask = new Runnable() {
    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            squaresglow();
            //...
            Thread.sleep(2500); //2.5 sec before cleanup occurs
            cleanup();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        notify(); //make sure we call notify even if interrupted
    }
};
void mainmethod() {
    //...
    if (bPointWasScored) {
        synchronized (pointScoredTask) {
            try {
                Thread psThread = new Thread(pointScoredTask,"pointscored");
                psThread.start(); //thread will start to call run(), but we get control back to avoid race condition
                pointScoredTask.wait(6000); //wait no more than 6 sec for the notify() call
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            } 
        }
        //if a point was scored, nothing past this line will execute until scoreglow has been cleaned up 
    }
    //...
    purpleSquare();
    //...
}
```

I know you'd rather avoid threads, but there are some things that just work much better when you use them.  Try the above design and see if that works out the synchronization issues you were seeing.