# synchronized blocks containing method calls, will this work?

Tags: android, arrays, synchronization, handler, runnable

Is the code below legit for synchronizing myIntArray?
Will it prevent the three bottom methods from changing myIntArray out of order?
I Want things to happen in the order delayedMethod1, delayedMethod2, method3 and not have one of them screwed up by running before the previous one has finished its changes to myIntArray.
Do the bottom 3 method declarations need the synchronized keywords?
Do the bottom 3 methods need to contain synchronized(myIntArray) blocks?
Should my synchronized block be around the Runnable rather than inside it?
Do I neet notify, wait, or join commands?

```
            public class HelpPlease {

                public int myIntArray[] = new int[100];

                public void chooseSquare() {

                    ...
                    Handler handler=new Handler();
                    final Runnable r = new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {   
                            synchronized(myIntArray) {
                                delayedMethod1();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

                    ...

                    Handler handler2=new Handler();
                    final Runnable r2 = new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {    
                            synchronized(myIntArray) {
                                delayedMethod2();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    handler2.postDelayed(r2, 1000);

                    ...

                    synchronized(myIntArray) {
                        method3();
                    }
               }

               public void delayedMethod1() {
                    ...
                    change myIntArray;
                    otherMethodsABC();
               {

               public void delayedMethod2() {
                    ...
                    change myIntArray;
                    otherMethodsDEF();
               }

               public void method3() {
                    ...
                    change myIntArray;
                    otherMethodsGHI();
               }
           }
```

More details: [Handler/Runnable delays producing events that are out of sync sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787523/handler-runnable-delays-producing-events-that-are-out-of-sync-sometimes)

EDIT:

Does this make sense? To run a thread a wait for it to finish? Not sure how to add the delay tho, and that was the whole point.

```
                        //Handler handler=new Handler();
                        final Runnable r = new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                delayedMethod();
                            }
                        };
                        //handler.postDelayed(r, COMPUTER_MOVE_DELAY);

                        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

                        final Future f1 = es.submit(r);

                        try
                           {
                               f1.get();
                           }
                           catch (InterruptedException e)
                           {
                               throw new RuntimeException(e);
                           }
                           catch (ExecutionException e)
                           {
                               throw new RuntimeException(e);
                           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try doing this with synchronized blocks. It will only guarantee that no two blocks will run *simultaneously*, not which order they run. You'd be better off writing a "parent" runnable that executes the delayed methods in the order you want. Alternatively, you can have the first method, when it is finished, post a runnable to run the second, etc., chaining them together.

To be more specific, if you want a delay and then for the three methods to run in sequence, I'd code it like this:

```
public class HelpPlease {
    public int myIntArray[] = new int[100];
    Handler handler=new Handler();

    public void chooseSquare() {
        ...
        final Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                delayedMethod1();
                delayedMethod2();
                method3();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    }

    public void delayedMethod1() {
        ...
        change myIntArray;
        otherMethodsABC();
    }

    public void delayedMethod2() {
        ...
        change myIntArray;
        otherMethodsDEF();
    }

    public void method3() {
        ...
        change myIntArray;
        otherMethodsGHI();
    }
}
```

No need for synchronization at all. It's important to use a single `Handler` to guarantee that multiple calls to `chooseSquare()` will result in serialized execution of the runnables.

EDIT:

Based on your latest comments, here's how I'd proceed. First, have a single `Handler` object that is accessible by all your action scheduling code. To use your two examples, these could then be implemented as follows:

```
public void chooseSquare() {
    . . .
    if (point_scored) {
        makeSquaresGlow(list_of_squares);
        playSound(sound_to_play);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                makeSquaresNotGlow(list_of_squares);
            }
        }, 1000L);
    }
    if (time_for_attack(purple)) {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                launchAttack(purple);
            }
        }, 1000L);
    }
}
```

Assuming that `chooseSquare()` is called on the event thread, everything (including the delayed method calls) will also run on the same thread, so no synchronization is needed. There may be race conditions (`launchAttack` and `makeSquaresNotGlow` will be scheduled at the same time), but `handler` will execute one at a time. If the sequencing of these delayed actions is vital, you can define a "meta" action `Runnable` that accepts a sequence of actions and executes them in a prescribed order at a future time.

Comment: I could use a little more info. All I'm really trying to do is have a delay in a game. Does parent runnable mean something like ThreadPoolExecutor? or some kind of array of runnables?

Comment: @NewUserSOF - I added sample code to my answer. I don't think a thread pool is at all necessary for what you want. As I understand it, you are trying to eliminate parallelism (via synchronization, which isn't working), not introduce more of it by having multiple threads. (By the way, having multiple Handler objects is probably adding to your troubles.)

Comment: Thanks again, I don't want to wait one delay and then run 3 methods. I have various game events (that may or may not happen depending on game conditions) that each need their own delay. Though each may not always happen, there is an order to them when they do.

Comment: @NewUserSOF - Does that mean that calling `chooseSquare()` (for instance) should trigger the execution of a series of actions to be executed on some schedule? And that the specific actions and schedule are determined by the game conditions and cannot be cataloged in advance? Also, do these actions involve updating the UI or are they modifications to the game state that can be done in a worker thread?

Comment: chooseSquare will call various IF's and methods that need to be executed in the order they are presented, some with one second delays. The various possible scenarios could be defined in advance - they are limited. The actions very much involve updating the UI (and gamestate).

Comment: For example, chooseSquare, did they score a point?, make the squares glow, play a sound, wait a second and then run the cleanup script to blank out the squares, is it time for the random Purple attack? if so wait a second and then do it, is it the computer's turn to make a move? wait a second and then let it make a move...

Comment: @NewUserSOF - I added more to my answer to address this.

Comment: I have changed to a single Handler as you advise. A problem I have is when purpleattack runs before cleanup is finished. So I don't just want to control the order of events I want to control what has to be finished before another thing can start.

Comment: @NewUserSOF - It sounds like you need a logic layer that handles that kind of sequencing (where an action is enabled only when certain preconditions are met). It's not something you will be able to deal with by clever use of a handler and/or synchronizing. (Like I said in my edit, synchronizing is not a factor with everything already executing on a single thread). I'd recommend that you define the specific sequencing issues you face, narrow them down to a relatively simple problem example, and post it as a new question.